# How can I make a video by entering video location in input

Tags: javascript, html, video

I want to make an input that creates a video. This is what I tried:
HTML

```
<form>
   <input type="text" id="txtSRC" />
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SetSrc()" />
</form>
<video>
   <source src="" type="video/mp4" id="myIframe">
</video>
```

JS

```
function SetSrc() {
            document.getElementById("myIframe").src = "" + document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
        }
```

Comment: where is the code of `myIframe`

Comment: @B001ᛦ `myIframe` is the HTML video element ID, not a function

Comment: @Seblor I am aware of that. My question was where is the html code of the iframe called myIframe - Then I've noticed the "source" element

Answer (score 0):

When changing the `src` attribute of a `source` HTML element, you need to force the wrapping `video` element to load again. Here is an example :

```js
function SetSrc() {
  document.getElementById("myIframe").src = "" + document.getElementById("txtSRC").value;
  document.getElementById("videoElement").load();
  document.getElementById("videoElement").play();
}
```

```html
<form>
   <input type="text" id="txtSRC" />
   <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="SetSrc()" />
</form>
<video id="videoElement" controls>
   <source src="" type="video/mp4" id="myIframe">
</video>
```

(The `controls` attribute on the video and the auto play are optional, depending on your use case)